# Excel vba2007 copy comment as cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy comments from excel cells(3,2) as cell values to another cells(7,5) of different sheet of same workbook using VBA.
I have written the following code but it is not working. In fact, the following code is copying the first comment it found in sheet1:

```
Set commentstrg = _ activeworkbook.sheets("sheet1").cells(3,2).special _ cells(xlcelltypecomments)
Getcomments = commentstrg.comment.text
Activeworkbook.sheets("sheet2").cells(7,5).value = getcomments
```

Comment: It has the option of paste special,comments but want to make above lines as a part of a macro...

Comment: i think your line splits have ended up on the same line (see continuation character)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used the function and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
With ActiveWorkbook
    .Sheets("sheet2").Cells(7,5) = .Sheets("sheet1").Cells(3,2).Comment.Text
End With
```

You could convert this to a [function](https://chandoo.org/wp/2009/09/03/get-cell-comments/) (adapted from @Chandoo) and also add code to remove the author:

As function:

```
Function getComment(ByVal incell As Range) As String
' aceepts a cell as input and returns its comments (if any) back as a string
On Error Resume Next
getComment = incell.Comment.Text
End Function
```

Remove author:

```
=Right$(getcomment(inCell),Len(getcomment(inCell))-Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(":",getcomment(inCell)))
```

Which could also be written into the function as:

```
Function getComment(ByVal incell As Range) As String
' aceepts a cell as input and returns its comments (if any) back as a string
On Error Resume Next
getComment = Right$(incell.Comment.Text, Len(incell.Comment.Text)-Len(incell.Comment.Author) + 1))
End Function
```

The function calls having the advantage of not throwing an error if no comment is present in the range passed as an argument.